# Launcher app not in chooser

Tags: android, android-launcher

I'm in the process of making a Launcher app, but I can't get my app to show up in the activity chooser when the home button is pressed. I'm sure I'm just missing something simple, but I can't find it! Here's my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.espian.jump"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<application
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name="JumpActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing that

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

with

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

As it says in the android [intent filter documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html):

> activities that are willing to receive implicit intents must include
>   "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" in their intent filters

Actually I'd suggest opening that page and searching for that text, and having a little read around it. I think you'll find these categories make a lot more sense if you do. You're specifying that this appears in the launcher instead.

Comment: Knew it was something like that, I always miss out the default category flag. Thanks!